# Which HTML5 tags to use to wrap definitions and examples in a dictionary?

Tags: html

What is the best way to HTML5ify this?

```
follow: Go or come after (a person or thing proceeding ahead); move or travel behind.

"She went back into the house, and Ben followed her."
```

This?

```
<article>
<dfn>follow</dfn>: Go or come after (a person or thing proceeding ahead); move or travel behind.
<q>"She went back into the house, and Ben followed her."</q>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your definition is more extensive like an encyclopedia article (example, wiki), I would not call it an article since the `<article>` tag:

```
Represents a section of a page that consists of a composition that forms an     
independent part of a document, page, or site. This could be a forum post, 
a magazine or newspaper article, a Web log entry, a user-submitted comment, 
or any other independent item of content.
```

For a series of short definitions that you might have in an appendix of a book or white paper, I would suggest using a data definition list: `<dl>` width `<dt>` and `<dd>` to mark-up the term and definition respectively.

Reference: http://html5doctor.com

There is much discussion about how best to use HTML5 tags, makes for interesting reading.

**How I Might Style This**

If I were making a simple definition list for a glossary, I might start with:

```
<dl>
   <dt><dfn>follow</dfn>:</dt>
    <dd>
        <p>Go or come after (a person or thing proceeding ahead); move or travel
            behind.</p>
        <q>She went back into the house, and Ben followed her.</q>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

and apply some styling as follows:

```
dl {
    border: 1px solid #989898;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 1.00em;
}
dt {
    margin-left: 1.00em;
}
dfn {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}
dd {
    margin-left: 2.00em;
    margin-bottom: 3.00em;
}
dd p {
    margin: 0 0 0.50em 0;
}
dd q {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 0.50em 0;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

This is just an illustration of how much flexibility and control you have over the various elements in the layout.

Fiddle Reference: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/H6593/

Comment: I would really appreciate if you can also provide me an insight about how to tag the example sentences in this case. Maybe it's not a big deal but I still want to design it good from the start.

Comment: I provided a sample HTML/CSS to illustrate how one might approach the layout and styling.

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes a complete answer.

Comment: You are very welcome, glad to help!  Please consider up voting the question is you found the answer insightful.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 elements aren't needed, it's a case for the good old `dl`, `dt` and `dd`.

e.g.

```
<dl>
    <dt>Thing one</dt>
    <dd>
        <p>This defines thing one.</p>
    </dd>

    <dt>Thing two</dt>
    <dd>
        <p>This defines thing two.</p>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

`dl` is a definition list, `dt` is a definition term, and `dd` is the definition description.

Comment: OK, question changed somewhat, but this is your basic markup for this situation.

Comment: What about the examples (tag-wise)? -yes, someone edited my question

Comment: HTML5 does slightly change the meaning of `dl`, `dt` and `dd`, though. The first `d` now means "description" in general rather than just "definition", so your `dt`s would need to contain `dfn`s which in turn contain the terms.

Comment: @BoltClock Your comment is especially relevant if the author is considering how the content will appear in the document outline (which is not yet implemented in any browser, as far as I know).